# Examples of discrete time martingales

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

In probability, a martingale is given by a sequence of integrable 
  random variables $(S_n)$ and an increasing sequence of 
  $\sigma$-algebras ${\cal F}_n$ such that
  $S_n$ is ${\cal F}_n$-measurable and 
  $E(S_{n+1} \mid {\cal F}_n) = S_{n}$.

This is an important notion because there are many results concerning
  convergence of martingales sequences, e.g. if it is bounded in $L^2$
  then it converges in $L^2$ norm and $a.e.$

If $X_i$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables and 
  ${\cal F}_n = \sigma(X_i, i\leq n)$, then the following sequences 
  are martingales:

- $S_n - E(S_n)$,
- $ \exp(S_n)/E(\exp(S_n))$,
- $(S_n)^2-E(S_n^2)$,

These are used in the theory of random walks to compute e.g. the mean time before reaching a given state.

Are there any other interesting examples of discrete time martingales?

Comment: This is a little like asking "are there any other interesting examples of groups?" to which one must answer "yes". A broad class of examples is furnished by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin's_formula

Comment: Your definition is for discrete-time martingales. but of course there is also continuous time.  Brownian motion is the first example there, and of course all the martingales that are produced by the stochastic integral.  This ties into the "martingale problem" and all of probabilistic potential theory.

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}$ $\newcommand{\eF}{\mathscr{F}}$ $\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}$

**Branching processes** Set $\bN_0=\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$. Fix a probability measure $\mu$ on $\bN_0$ such that
$$
m:=\sum_{k\in\bN_0}k\mu\bigl(\,\{k\}\,\bigr)<\infty
$$
and $\mu(\{k_0\})>0$ for some $k_0>1$. Consider next a sequence $(X_{n,j})_{j,n\in\bN_0}$ of i.i.d. $\bN_0$-valued random variables   with common probability distribution $\mu$. Fix $\ell\in \bN_0$, $\ell>0$,  set $Z_0=\ell$. For  $n\in\bN_0$ define
$$
Z_{n+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{Z_n} X_{n,j},\;\;\eF_n=\si\bigl(\, X_{k,j};\, k\in\bN_0, k<n\,\bigr).
$$
The random variable $Z_n$  can be interpreted as the population of the $n$-th generation of a species that had $\ell$ individuals at $n=0$ and such that  the number of offsprings of a given individuals is a random variable with distribution $\mu$.

Then $Y_n=m^{-n}Z_n$ is a martingale.

**Polya's urn scheme**  An urn contains $r>0$ red  balls and $g>0$ green balls. Fix an integer $c\geq 0$.  Every unit of  time, we draw a ball, and we replace it by $c+1$ balls of the same color as the one drawn. Denote by $R_n$  and $G_n$ the number of red and respectively green balls in the urn after the $n$-th draw, and set 
$$
X_n:=\frac{R_n}{R_n+G_n},\;\;\eF_n=\si(R_0,G_0,\dotsc , R_n, G_n).
$$
Then $(X_\bullet)$ is an $\eF_\bullet$-martingale.

**Markov chains** Suppose that $(X_n)_{n\in\bN_0}$ is a Markov chain with  countable state space $E$ and  transition matrix $P=\big(P(i,j)\big)_{i,j\in E}$ $\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}$ $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$
$$
P(i,j)=\bP(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i).
$$
For any function $f: E\to \bR$ we define $Pf:E\to\bR$
$$ Pf(i)=\sum_jP(i,j)f(j). $$

Then the sequence $$Y_n= f(X_n)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\Big( Pf(X_k)-f(X_k)\;\Big) $$

is a martingale.

**Doob martingale**  Suppose that  $f:[0,1]\to\bR$ is an integrable   function. Denote by $\eF_n$ the sigma algebra generated by  the intervals $I_{k,n}:=\big(\;(k-1)/2^n, k/2^n\;\big)$, $k=1,\dotsc ,2^n$.

Define $f_n:[0,1]\to\bR$

$$
f_n(x)= 2^n\int_{I_{k,n}} f(t) dt ,\;\;x\in I_{k,n}. 
$$

Then the sequence $(f_n)$  is an $\eF_n$-martingale.

Comment: As an aside, your Markov chain example is basically Dynkin's formula, which I mentioned in a comment on the original question.

Answer (score 4):

- If $X$ is an integrable random variable and $\left(\mathcal F_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a filtration, then $X_n:=\mathbb E\left[X\mid\mathcal F_n\right]$ is a martingale. It is worth mentioning that the sequence $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges in $\mathbb L^1$ and almost surely to $\mathbb E\left[X\mid\mathcal F\right]$, where $\mathcal F$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\mathcal F_n$ (this is known as the martingale convergence theorem).
- Martingale with stationary increments have been intensively studied. The setting is the following. We have a probability space $\left(\Omega, \mathcal F,\mu\right)$ and an invertible map $T\colon\Omega\to\Omega$ which is bi-measurable and measure preserving. For any function $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R$, the sequence $\left(f\circ T^j\right)_{j\geqslant 0}$ is strictly stationary and each strictly stationary sequence can be represented in this way. Now, let $\mathcal F_0$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal F$ such that $\mathcal F_0\subset T^{-1}\mathcal F_0$. In this way, $\left(T^{-i}\mathcal F_0\right)_{i\geqslant 0}$ is a filtration. If $m$ is an $\mathcal F_0$-measurable function such that $\mathbb E \left[m  \mid T\mathcal F_0 \right]=0$, then the sequence $\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}m\circ T^i\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a martingale. The partial sums satisfy good deviation and moment inequalities. Moreover, in this setting, the sums of conditional variances is of the form $ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^i$ where $f=\mathbb E\left[m^2\mid T\mathcal F_0\right]$ hence can be handled with the maximal ergodic theorem.

Answer (score 4):

**Change of probability**

An old remembrance, and I don't daily practice maths for a long time, so please correct me if I'm wrong. Let ${(\mathcal{F}_n)}_{n \geq 0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. Introduce a new probability $\mathbb{Q} = D.\mathbb{P}$ (i.e. $D=\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}$). Then $\mathbb{Q}_{|\mathcal{F}_n} = D_n . \mathbb{P}_{|\mathcal{F}_n}$ and $(D_n)$ is a martingale.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in a somewhat off-beat example of a discrete martingale, you could look at

Rafe Jones, Iterated Galois towers, their associated martingales, and
the $p$-adic Mandelbrot set, *Compos. Math.* **143** (2007), 1108-1126.

This is really a result in discrete dynamics over finite fields, and Jones uses tools from number theory (Galois theory, chebotarev density theorem) to show that a certain system constructed by iterating polynomials over finite fields is a martingale, and he then uses the convergence of martingales to deduce his final result.

(For those who don't have access to *Compositio*, there's a pre-print version on Jones's website: http://www.people.carleton.edu/~rfjones/Preprints/Jones_Iterated_Towers_Homepage.pdf)